# How to revert a unpushed git commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am using Idea IntelliJ Community Edition 2016 and committed a change to GIT. But I have not pushed it. Now when I see my push queue I can see it in the queue. I tried `RESET HEAD option` but it did not work. I want to delete that commit. How can I do it in Intellij?

Comment: If you don't want to preserve any local changes, I find the easiest thing to do is just delete the local branch and checkout a fresh copy from the remote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the latest version, you simply go to `version control`, right click the commit and select `Undo Commit`. This will put the changes back into a change list (so you can edit if needed) and remove the commit. You can remove the change list / revert the changes if you want them gone completely.

Using the `Reset HEAD` option should work too, just make sure to select a correct target and set an appropriate reset type (`Mixed` if you want to keep the changes, `Hard` if you want the changes gone too). To make it easier to find the target, you can find a `Reset Current Branch to Here` option when right clicking a commit in `version control`.

Answer (score 5):

1. $ git commit -m "Something terribly misguided"
2. $ git reset HEAD~
3. << edit your files files as necessary >>
4. $ git add ...
5. $ git commit -c ORIG_HEAD

Answer (score 4):

In that `VCS > Git > Reset HEAD` dialog from IntelliJ, you wanted to:

- select `Soft` as the `Reset Type` (to keep the changes of the undone commit)
- use `HEAD^` as the commit (to point 1 commit back in the history of your branch)

[image: example]

That is equivalent to the following git command: `git reset --soft HEAD^`